# Decimal('1') is not converted to 1.0 using parse_args

Tags: python, rest, flask, put, flask-restful

I have the following PUT method and helper method:

```
from decimal import Decimal
def to_decimal(arg):
    try:
        return Decimal(arg)
    except ValueError:
        pass

class StudentResource(Resource):
    parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        'name',
        type=str,
        trim=True,
        help='Name of student.',
        required=True)
    parser.add_argument(
        'hight', 
        type=to_decimal, 
        help='hight of student.', 
        location='json')
    parser.add_argument(
        'weight', 
        type=to_decimal, 
        help='weight of student.', 
        location='json')
    

    @api.doc(description='Updates an existing student record.')
    @api.marshal_with(STUDENT_MODEL)
    def put(self, student_id):
        student = Student.find_by_id(student_id)

        data = self.parser.parse_args()
        #content of data:
        #{'student': 'John Mike', 'hight': None, 'weigth': None}

        for key, value in data.items():
            setattr(student, key, value)

        student.save()
        return student
```

and my pytest is the following:

```
def test_update_student_success(test_client, db_session, auth_headers):
    student = StudentFactory()
    student_updated = StudentFactory()

    data = {
        'name': student_updated.name,
        'hight': student_updated.hight,
        'weight': student_updated.weight
    }
    #data dictionary content:
    # {'name': 'John Mike', 'weight': Decimal('-57.9914295'), 'height': Decimal('-155.862692')}
    resp = test_client.put(
        f'/student/{student.id}',
        data=data,
        headers=auth_headers['full_auth_header'])
    #resp.data:
    # b'{"id":"144c9b0d-c32c-4059-babb-bfd4a0866fe6","student_name":"John Mike","weight":null,"height":null}\n'
    
    put_data = json.loads(resp.data.decode())

    assert resp.status_code == 200 #Success
    assert put_data['name'] == data['name'] #Success
    assert put_data['hight'] == data['hight'] #Fails
    assert put_data['weight'] == data['weight'] #Fails
```

As a note, the first tried included the function in the type field as follows:

```
parser.add_argument(
        'weight', 
        type=type=lambda x: Decimal(x) if x else None, 
        help='weight of student.', 
        location='json')
```

Considering the previous scenario, how can I avoid getting `None` from value passed as `Decimal('1')` when executing this line:

```
data = self.parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: JSON doesn't have a Decimal type, how are you encoding it?

Comment: just skip `StudentFactory`, `@api.marshal_with` etc and show example only with `argparse`. what is `test_client` and how you send data? (`json`, `multipart` etc).